# Using grep to overwrite its current file

Tags: linux, terminal, overwrite

I have a list of directories within directories and this is what I am trying to attempt:

- find a specific file format which is `.xml`
- within all these .xml files, read the contents in the files and remove line 3

For line 3, its string is as follows: `dxflib <Name of whatever folder it is in>.dxb`

I tried using `find -name "*.xml" | xargs grep -v "dxflib"` in the terminal (I am using linux) and I found out that while my code works and it displays the results, it did not overwrite the changes to the file.

And as I googled online, it is mentioned that I will need to add in `>> output.txt` etc

And hence, are there anyways in which I can make it to save / overwrite its own file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removes third line in file:

```
sed -i '3d' file
```

Comment: I have managed to know how to do a mass change of it - `find -name "*.obj" | xargs sed -i '3d'` However, I was wondering, if I have run this command and remove line 3 in all my 12 files for example. And 3 months later, there are more files (eg. 30 files) and some of them are still having the line 3 error. Supposedly if I run the command again, I believed it will remove the line 3 of the 'good' file and 'bad' file. Is there any ways that I could have done to prevent it?

Comment: I am using this command - `find -name "*.obj" | xargs sed -i  /^dxflib/d'` to search and remove lines starting with `dxflib`. It does seems to work and it is not affecting the other files should I be running the command again. Now I a trying to time how lond this command will takes me by adding in `time` in front of the command, but I keep getting 0.001s which I doubt so as I am certainly waiting for more than a second... any ideas?

Comment: `find -name "*.obj" | xargs sed -i '/^dxflib/d'` works for me.

Comment: The command indeed works. Just time when I tried to time it, the display results is not making sense. Anyway, can the `sed` command read directories with spaces in them? While it is working on the other files, it seems to fails on those files where its folder's name contain spaces in them

Comment: I see. That is not problem of `sed`, that is problem of the way you passing it arguments. Luckily, `xargs` can read data separated by null character and `find` can write them that way. `find -name "*.obj" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '/^dxflib/d'`.